# How to make Esp32-Cam blink when face is recognized

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I've found several tutorials on how to set up a video-streaming server, how to get information, for example the temperature and humidity, via telegram or how to save a face so it gets recognized with Esp32-Cam. But I've found nowhere on the whole internet an example for my problem. I want the Esp32-Cam to light an LED when it recognizes a face. That should be possible, shouldn't it? There are a lot of pins which can be used as output. Does someone have a idea how to do that? When I have the light I want it to rotate a stepper motor too. I'de very grateful for your help :)
kind regards
the andorian guard

Comment: Googling "esp32 gpio led" gives you more tutorials than you can shake a stick at. Googling "esp32 stepper motor" a bit less, but still quite good. What's the problem?

Comment: It's not an Esp32 it's an Esp32-CAM. And it should not blink all the time it should blink when it recognizes a face. That's the problem

Comment: ESP32-CAM is an ESP32, with some extra peripherals attached to it. There is no reason to view it as a special case. All the tutorials and other documentation written for vanilla ESP32 boards (e.g. the DevKitC) apply to it. Pick any GPIO pin which is available and unused on your board, connect a LED+resistor and tell the Arduino GPIO library to toggle the pin. This is the simplest, most common "hello world" project you can do with an embedded system; and certainly very well covered by tutorials. Making it blink when it recognizes a face is subsequently yours to solve as a programmer.

Comment: If anyone has the same problem and reads this, I found a tutorial https://robotzero.one/esp32-face-door-entry/ 
 thank you :)